# brian variables save load python

Tags: python, save, load, pickle

I am new to Python and, in particular, I am new to using Brian (http://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) a simulator for spiking neural networks. This feels like a dumb question, but I am simply trying to save the Brian variables and can't figure out how.

I ran code that looks like this:

```
stimulus_train = TimedArray(input_rates_train, dt=presentation_time)
P_train = PoissonGroup(num_input_neurons, 
rates='stimulus_train(t,i)')
MP_train = SpikeMonitor(P_train)
net_train = Network(P_train, MP_train)
net_train.run(presentation_time*num_samples_train)
spikes_train_i = MP_train.i
spikes_train_t = MP_train.t
```

For example, I want to save MP_train which has type
    brian2.monitors.spikemonitor.SpikeMonitor

I've tried pickling the data:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump( MP_train, open( "MNIST_Poisson_dataset.p", "wb" ) )
```

but get the error:
    TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects

Does anyone have experience with this?

Edit: I've attempted h5py, and dill with no success. The only thing that works at the moment is to extract variables from MP_train and save them as numpy arrays. While this works, it is a bit annoying and would love a way to save MP_train directly.

Comment: Just stumbled across this post. 1) Making a copy of an object for which you only have a weakref can be very complicated ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46203335/creating-a-deepcopy-of-class-instance-with-nested-weakref-to-it)). This is not unique to brian(2) but true for all python objects.

Comment: 2) Pickling an object when you only need the data attributes is generally not a good idea because you need to have the class definition in your current namespace to reconstruct the object when unpickling. If you change the class definition (code evolves and you have no control over the SpikeMonitor class in b2), then unpickling will fail. Only saving the arrays is hence much more portable.