# python performs a deepcopy of a weakref.proxy's content. Why? Which entity owns the reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-copy, weak-references

I wanted to double check my assumption, that the content of a `weakref.proxy` is not deepcopied when performing a deepcopy of it. To that end, I wrote the following code snippet:

```py
import copy
import weakref

class A:
    def __init__(self, val=3):
        self.val = val

    def identify(self):
        return id(self)

a = A()

proxy = weakref.proxy(a)
proxy.val = 4
proxy_deepcopy = copy.deepcopy(proxy)
proxy_deepcopy.val = 5

print(a.val, a.identify())                            # 4 139732708115984
print(proxy.val, proxy.identify())                    # 4 139732708115984
print(proxy_deepcopy.val, proxy_deepcopy.identify())  # 5 139732690146640
```

However my assumption seems to be incorrect; a deepcopy of `a` is performed when deepcopying the `proxy`. Am I misinterpreting the results of the tests or do I have a misconception of how the `weakref.proxy` is supposed to work? Shouldn't the copied instance of `A` be immediately be GCed?

I checked on the internet and found that the expected behavior occurs when using `weakref.ref` instead of the `weakref.proxy` (which I thought was mainly semantic sugar).

Because of this [line in the CPython copy module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9bb202a1a90ef0edce20c495c9426d9766df11bb/Lib/copy.py#L188) that I found reading up on [this stack overflow answer on weakref.ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46205191/12769783) utilizing weakref.ref yields the results I would have expected:

```py
proxy = weakref.ref(a)
proxy().val = 4
proxy_deepcopy = copy.deepcopy(proxy)
proxy_deepcopy().val = 5

print(a.val, a.identify())                                # 5 140323837493200
print(proxy().val, proxy().identify())                    # 5 140323837493200
print(proxy_deepcopy().val, proxy_deepcopy().identify())  # 5 140323837493200
```

Is this discrepancy between weakref.proxy and weakref.ref intended?

Who is the owner of the deepcopied instance of `A`, that is still accessible through the `proxy_deepcopy`?

Executed with `CPython` 3.8.18 and 3.10.13.